# When selecting a message in mobile chat, action icons do not appear until scrolling

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, android, mobile-chrome

For some time now, whenever I select a chat message by tapping it on mobile device, there are no action icons:

> [image: no action icons]

However when scrolling, either up or down, the icons appear:

> [image: action icons appear after scrolling]

Can the icons please appear when selecting a message, not only after scrolling?

Browser: mobile Chrome 66, android device. Can also reproduce though on desktop Chrome 66 by emulating mobile device via the dev console.

Also, after scrolling once, the issue goes away until reloading the page, i.e. when selecting a message the action icons appear right away.

Comment: They appear straight away on iOS Chrome

Comment: Reproduced on my Android device.

Comment: well, things are a bit different here: the bug occurs every time I select a message. Even if I scroll the page and the toolbar re-appears, the bug happens again if I deselect and then select another message (no refreshing)

Comment: Funny, I always thought ​this was by design. Chrome 70 from Google Play, phone on Android 5.1

Comment: @Jenayah no, it used to work just fine until a while ago. (Few weeks before I posted this)